# How can one use RingCT to maximize the privacy of existing wallets?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, ringct, privacy

I think the privacy is not what it should be in my existing wallets is because 1) there are old zero mixin transactions there and 2) it is my understanding that it is possible to estimate the amounts of even non zero mixin transactions in some cases.

I would like to use the Jan 2016 implementation of RingCT to maximize the privacy of my existing wallets as it specifically addresses these problems.  How is it best to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to sweep all your inputs to your own address and the new inputs (if transaction was mad with ringct of course) will be in the new RingCT format